# How to modify maximum page of database externally?

Tags: sqlite

I tried to modify the maximum page of a database externally.

The code I  used was

```
 sqlite3 database.sqlite 'PRAGMA main.max_page_count = 2147483646;'
```

It returns

```
 2147483646
```

However, when I open the database and check the maximum page by

```
PRAGMA main.max_page_count;
```

It returned 1073741823.
When I modify the maximum page in sqlite3 interface by

```
PRAGMA main.max_page_count = 2147483646;
```

The maximum page was modified successfully. What should I do to modify this externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max_page_count` setting is a runtime option that doesn't persist across connections to a database:

```
$ sqlite3 foo.db
SQLite version 3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> pragma max_page_count=600;
max_page_count
--------------
600           
sqlite> .quit
$ sqlite3 foo.db    
SQLite version 3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> pragma max_page_count;
max_page_count
--------------
1073741823
```

If you look at the [description of the database header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_database_header) you'll see there's no field for the maximum page count. Much like things like turning on foreign key support, you have to explicitly set a limit on every connection. Or you can compile a custom version with [`SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT`](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_page_count) defined to the value you want.